# How to return a variable from a destructor

Tags: c++

So I have a struct called timer which determines how much time did a block of code take to execute and complete and I'm going to run few benchmarks on my sorting algorithm and take the average value of time it took for each sorting algorithm.

```
struct Example{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, end;
    Example() {
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    ~Example() {
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float>  duration = end - start;
        float ms = duration.count() * 1000.0f;
        std::cout << ms << " miliseconds\n";
        // a way to return ms?
    }
};
```

However, I was not able to find a way to get the variable ms out of the destructor and assign it to something after measuring the time. Is there any way to get it out or can I write my struct in a better way?

Comment: You'll have to put the value in something else the object has a pointer to, or a global variable or class-static member.

Comment: You could have a `std::optional<float>` as a `static` member and check it via some interface (set it whenever an object is destroyed and delete the value after it is checked), but that is only a workaround

Comment: Why does it have to be the destructor? Just make a member function?

Comment: it has to be in destructor because it gets destroyed in that scope and prints out the time it took for scope to be executed

Comment: @aschepler can u explain me an example i tried to do that but it did not work :(

Comment: It is not possible for a destructor to return a value. `Example`'s constructor could require a pointer, potentially a `shared_ptr` depending on usage, to where you want the result to be created. Another approach would be to provide `Example` with a function like `std::future<float> get_future()` which returns an object where the result will be placed.

Comment: its actually a good idea to use a `shared_ptr`. thanks

Comment: You could throw an exception (*shiver*). But giving Example a reference to store the time in the constructor is the right solution. Or rewrite the interface to take a callable (function, lambda, object with `operator()`) and measure how long calling it takes. No destructor needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't return anything from the deststructor but you can assign the value to a variable that you supply to `Example` upon creation. Example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

template <class Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock>
struct Example {
    std::chrono::time_point<Clock> start;
    std::chrono::duration<float>& duration;         // a reference

    Example(std::chrono::duration<float>& dur) :    // take the duration as an argument
        start(Clock::now()),
        duration(dur)
    {}

    ~Example() {
        auto end = Clock::now();
        duration = end - start; // assign the value
    }
};

int main() {
    std::chrono::duration<float> duration;
    {
        Example<> x(duration);
    }
    std::cout << duration.count() << '\n';  // read it afterawrds
}
```